# Trying to send readable stream (audio) to amazon s3 - runtime error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to write a function that takes the mp3 url of the recording and then uploads that to S3. However, I keep getting a runtime error and the callback is never reached. If I move the callback below `s3.upload(...)` then the statement "attempting to upload mp3 is never logged.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  var getUri = require('get-uri');

  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "...",
    secretAccessKey: "..."
  });

  var client = context.getTwilioClient();
  const recording_id = event.RecordingSid;
  const uri = event.RecordingUrl + ".mp3";

  getUri(uri, function (err, rs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        throw err;
    }
    var params = {
        ACL: "public-read",
        Body: rs,
        Bucket: "...",
        Key: "audio.mp3",
        ContentType: 'audio/mp3'
    };
    s3.upload(params, function(err,data) {
        console.log("attempting to upload mp3");
        if (err) {
            console.log("there is an error");
            console.log(err.status);
            throw err.message;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Your upload has been successful.");
          }
        callback(null, twiml);
      });
});


   console.log("at the end");
 };
```

Is there any other way to access the recording and put them in my public s3 bucket? Why is this never executing `s3.upload(...)`.
Any insights into this is helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you confirm  if audio_mp3 has the contents of mp3 or URL of the mp3

Comment: Oh it has the url of the mp3. If I copy-paste the url, I do get a screen with a seek bar that plays the correct recording

Comment: you are passing the URl and expecting the .mp3 file to be uploaded to s3

We need to have the code to download the data from the URL and then send that data to your body of put object. 


Here are the contents that you can pass to putobject Body :

Body — (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream) Object data.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use readable stream now and it's not working. I've updated the code above. Is there any other method? Should I use blobs? Thanks!

Comment: I have added the code to upload the song please go through it. i am able to successfully download a song from the URL and upload to s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Twilio regarding this they responded that Twilio Functions have a strict 5 second time-out and the upload from the Twilio Function to S3 Bucket takes more than 5 seconds. My workaround was sending a string with all mp3 URLs separated by comma and a space. The lambda function would then parse through all the links and store all links in an array which would be used for audio playback.

Answer (score 0):

```
   app.get('/uploadsong',function(req,res){
    console.log("Hi there")
    var URI = 'http://sensongsmp3download.info/Kaala%20(2018)%20-%20Sensongsmp3.info/Thanga%20Sela%20--%20Sensongsmp3.Info.mp3';
    var buffer = [];

    request
        .get(URI)
        .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log("error")
    }).on('data',function(data){
        buffer.push(data);
    }).on('end',function(){
        var completeSong = Buffer.concat(buffer);

        var data = {
            Body:completeSong,
            Key: 'sample.mp3',
            ContentType: 'audio/mp3'
        }

        s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){ 
            if (err) 
            { 
                console.log('Error uploading data: ', data); 
            } else 
            {
                console.log('upload successfull')
                res.send('done');
            }

        })



    })

})
```

here are the modules i have used

```
var request = require('request');
```